# SQL statement SOMETIMES needs a lot of time

Tags: sql, oracle, join, spatial

I have a pretty long running query, about 16 seconds. Here it is:

```
SELECT 
   n.id as id1
   , n2.id as id2
from  
   nodesWays n
   , nodesWaysTag w
   , tag t
   , nodesWays n2
   , nodesWaysTag w2
   , tag t2
where 
   SDO_RELATE(n.shape, n2.shape, 'mask=ANYINTERACT') = 'TRUE'
   and n.id = w.geoid
   and w.tagid = t.id
   and t.key = 'waterway'
   and t.value = 'river'
   and n2.id = w2.geoid
   and w2.tagid = t2.id
   and t2.key = 'highway'
   and t2.value = 'tertiary';
```

This query is a spatial self-join. All spatial-related rivers and streets should be returned. 
To get the tag if a object is a river or street the joins over the nodesWays, nodesWaysTag and tag-Tables are neccessary, because it is an m:n-relationship.

My problem is that the query sometimes don't finish and when I interrupted it (because it needed too much time), SQL Developer shows "Task abgebrochen in 0 Sekunden" (Task interrupted in 0 Seconds). I have no idea why the task sometimes runs perfectly and sometimes don't give back a result.

When I don't interrupt it, the query does come to an end but it need a lot of time (300 seconds).

If someone has an idea why the query sometimes finished in 16 seconds and sometimes need 300 seconds, I am glad to hear.

Greetings, Andre

Comment: @marc_s: could you please cite the part of the standard which says comma-separated list of tables style is discontinued?

Comment: @marc_s: section 7.4, "from clause": `<from clause> ::= FROM <table reference> [ { <comma> <table reference> }... ]`

Comment: have you looked at the explain plan?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it does not help me. It does not explain why the query is sometimes running fast and sometimes needs a lot of time.

Comment: Do you get different query plans when the query is fast and when the query is slow?  Which wait events are different in the two cases?

Comment: The problem was that the statistics where not up to date. I calculate them new and now all is good :)